# Stacked bar chart in ggplot from this table

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a pretty complicated(at least for me it is haha) ggplot that I am trying to create from this data.

```
Issue = c("Difficulty receiving products in general", 
"Supplier compliance issues", "Supplier fraud, waste, or abuse", 
"Difficulty receiving products in general", "Difficulty receiving products in general", 
"Supplier fraud, waste, or abuse", "Supplier service issues", 
"Problems repairing due to service issues ", "Problems repairing due to service issues ", 
"Other", "Billing, coverage, coordination of benefits", "Problems repairing due to service issues ", 
"Difficulty receiving products in general", "Difficulty receiving products in general", 
"Low quantity/quality", "Difficulty receiving products in general", 
"Difficulty receiving products in general", "Supplier service issues", 
"Problems repairing due to service issues ", "Problems repairing due to service issues ", 
"Problems repairing due to service issues ", "Problems repairing due to lack of inventory ", 
"Supplier service issues", "Difficulty receiving products in general", 
"Supplier service issues")

Resolution = c("Current supplier resolved the issue", 
"Current supplier resolved the issue", "Current supplier resolved the issue", 
"Supplier educated about inquiry\n", "Beneficiary educated about inquiry ", 
"Supplier educated about inquiry\n", "Beneficiary educated about DMEPOS\n", 
"Beneficiary educated about inquiry ", "Beneficiary educated about inquiry ", 
"Beneficiary educated about inquiry ", "Beneficiary educated about suppliers", 
"The case unresolved ", "The case unresolved ", "Beneficiary educated about DMEPOS\n", 
"Current supplier resolved the issue", "Current supplier resolved the issue", 
"Beneficiary educated about DMEPOS\n", "Beneficiary educated about suppliers", 
"New supplier found ", "Beneficiary educated about suppliers", 
"Supplier educated about inquiry\n", "New supplier found ", 
"New supplier found ", "Beneficiary educated about DMEPOS\n", 
"The case unresolved ")

df <- data.frame(Issue,Resolution)
crosstable<- table(df$Issue,df$Resolution)
```

I want to create a stacked bar ggplot that has issues on the x axis, and then count on the y axis, but also shows how each issue is broken down by resolution.  This is pretty easy to do in excel, but since I am making other graphs in R i would like to keep the aesthetics consistent.

Comment: have you tried any `ggplot()` code yet? seems like a coding service request instead of a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Issue, fill = Resolution)) + geom_bar()
```

If that's not the order, just switch the placement of Issue and Resolution.